# react-media-previewer Invalid Hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When using react-media-previewer I got this error.
It has 2 versions of react, this lib uses react 17 but my project is 18.

Please help me to resolve it.

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem

Version: 1.3.7
React Version: 18.2.0

I tried npm link but got this error

> [!] Error: Could not resolve entry module (rollup.config.js).
> npm ERR! Error: Could not resolve entry module (rollup.config.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feedback: The reason is the conflict between multiple versions of React. Installing the latest version will resolve this issue.